# Django project on 80 port?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-server

Ι have developed a Django project and uploaded it to a cloud VΜ. Currently i have access to it through 8080 port.

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

If i enter the url without the 8080 port, it shows the "it works" page. How can i set my Django project to run by default on 80 port?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 server

Comment: do you have root access? lower number ports can only be opened by root, and you have to make sure nothing else is running on port 80

Answer (score 9):

As [docs say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port), `runserver` isn't meant as a deployment server.  It also mentions that you probably can't start it on port 80 unless you run it as root.

Comment: Where can i find a tutorial to upload it to the non deployment server?

Comment: @Dimitris, this should help you get started: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/

Comment: Just want to confirm for anyone interested that `sudo ./manage.py runserver 80` does indeed work. (Of course, don't use it for your actual production server!)

Comment: page not found.

Comment: @chovy https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/deployment/

Answer (score 4):

Here is the kind of file you will need to put in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled, you need to adjust the paths in it.  You also need to load mod_wsgi which you can do via apt-get.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.14:80>
ServerAdmin youremail@whatever.com

ServerName www.whatever.com
ServerAlias whatever.com

Alias /robots.txt  /home/dimitris/Python/mysite/site_media/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /home/dimitris/Python/mysite/site_media/favicon.png
Alias /static/     /home/dimitris/Python/mysite/site_media/static

WSGIDaemonProcess mysite user=dimitris processes=1 threads=5
WSGIProcessGroup mysite
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/dimitris/Python/mysite/deploy/mysqite_wsgi.py

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
LogLevel debug

ErrorLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.access.log combined

ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

Most of this assumes you are running in a virtualenv, that means you will need a wsgi file to get things running.  The above file sets up apache to run your "wsgi" file which looks something like this:

```
import os
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
import sys

with open("/tmp/mysite.sys.path", "w") as f:
  for i in sys.path:
    f.write(i+"\n")


#redirect sys.stdout to sys.stderr for libraries that use
#print statements for optional import exceptions.
sys.stdout = sys.stderr

sys.path.insert(0, abspath(join(dirname(__file__), "../../")))
sys.path.insert(0, abspath(join(dirname(__file__), "../../lib/python2.7/site-packages/")))

from django.conf import settings
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

mod_wsgi, then opens this one file and executes it.  application is the part that waits for requests from the webserver, and the rest behaves just like runserver except it can be multi-process and multi-threaded.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal while in a virtual environment, **run:**

```
sudo ./manage.py runserver 80
```

You will be asked for your password and it will run the server on port 80.

Comment: ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Comment: sudo: ./manage.py: command not found

Answer (score 1):

The first , to create and active the virtual env:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
```

```
source .venv/bin/activate
```

second , install django :

```
pip install django
```

and run dev server with sudo:

```
sudo .venv/bin/python3 manage.py runserver 80
```

then open `http://127.0.0.1/`

[image]